# Inline editing with icon on side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm trying to create an inline editing plugin for a new project, I'm working on. It should be very easy. Just an `fa-pencil` icon on side of the text, which should be edited.
Currently I've got HTML like so (simplified):

```
<div class="inline-edit-icon">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
</div>
<div class="inline-edit">
    <p id="doctor-info-text" class="inline-edit-text">{{userInfo.description}}</p>
    <textarea class="form-control inline-edit-input" ng-model="userInfo.description"></textarea>
</div>
```

And I'm triggering the visibility of the `.inline-edit-icon` div via jQuery:

```
$('.inline-edit-text').hover(function(e){
    var coordinates = $(this).offset();

    $('.inline-edit-icon').css('top', coordinates.top);
    $('.inline-edit-icon').css('left', coordinates.left - $('.inline-edit-icon').width());
    $('.inline-edit-icon').show();
}, function(){
    $('.inline-edit-icon').hide();
});
```

The problem is, I can't click on the icon, as it gets hidden before I get my mouse to it.
How can I keep it visible when the mouse is over either text or icon?

Comment: Setup a working snippet, and it will be easy to show you how to fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this example help you? Notice the changes I made with HTML AND CSS:

```
$('.inline-edit-text, .fa-pencil').hover(function(e){
    var coordinates = $(this).offset();
console.log(coordinates)
    //$('.inline-edit-icon').css('top', coordinates.top);
    //$('.inline-edit-icon').css('left', coordinates.left);
    $('.inline-edit-icon').show();
}, function(){
    $('.inline-edit-icon').hide();
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uc593cd3/)

Answer (score 1):

Add a container around your .inline blocks, and you trigger the hover on it.

Something like :

```
<div class="inline-container">
    <div class="inline-edit-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil">o</i>
    </div>
    <div class="inline-edit">
        <p id="doctor-info-text" class="inline-edit-text">{{userInfo.description}}</p>
        <textarea class="form-control inline-edit-input" ng-model="userInfo.description"></textarea>
    </div>

</div>
```

and the script part:

```
$('.inline-container').hover(function(e){
    var coordinates = $(this).children('.inline-edit').offset();
    var $icon = $(this).children('.inline-edit-icon');

    $icon.css('top', coordinates.top);
    $icon.css('left', coordinates.left - $icon.width());
    $icon.show();

}, function(){
    $('.inline-edit-icon').hide();
});
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qej24s5m/

Hope it's gonna help you.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events:

```
$('.inline-edit-text, .fa.fa-pencil').on('mouseenter',function(e){
    var coordinates = $(this).offset();
    $('.inline-edit-icon').css('top', coordinates.top);
    $('.inline-edit-icon').css('left', coordinates.left - $('.inline-edit-icon').width());
    $('.inline-edit-icon').show();
});


$('.inline-edit-text, .fa.fa-pencil').on('mouseleave',function(e){
    $('.inline-edit-icon').hide();

});
```